# Laravel 5.3 npm gulp not creating output files

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, laravel-5.3

I am using Laravel 5.3, node version: 5.7 and npm version: 3.6.

When I run the `gulp` (or even `gulp watch`) command I get the same output in terminal as I normally get, everything looks like it should, and it even tells me that it has written to the public/css folder *(image below)*. Navigating to the folder I can see no changes were made to the previous app.css file.
When I delete the file, the css directory remains empty after the gulp commands.

This is my gulpfile.js

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');  
require('laravel-elixir-vue-2'); 

elixir(mix => {
mix.sass('app.scss')
   .webpack('app.js');
});
```

This is the output I get in the terminal (iTerm on mac OSX):
[image]

But lik I said, the public folder remains empty. I can't tell for sure that I updated node or npm or not.. But I don't think I have.

Thanks for the help.

---

**EDIT:**
deleting the `node-modules` folder and running `npm install` again gives another error.. One I have never seen before:
[image]

Comment: do you have enough permission to `~/Code/blog` ?

Comment: Yes I do. Project is working properly for a week or two now..